# Display time to crack password in 2 different scenarios

Tags: password, information-design

I'm making an alternative to Roboform's [How Secure is my Password](https://howsecureismypassword.net)

[image: How Secure is My Password example]

with Dropbox's [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn).

A cool feature of zxcvbn is that it not only returns the amount of time required for cracking the password offline with the hash, but also returns an estimated time for brute forcing it online.  How can I show my (probably) nontechnical users the difference between these two stats without a long text explanation?

Comment: It depends on your users, but I'd argue most won't care and it will be relatively meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just display your reply based on shortest of the two metrics. And, for those who will be interested in how you calculated it or won't trust you, add a link to detailed explanation/numbers.

Ideally an explanation that nontechnical users will find interesting/funny. For example I would appreciate explanation whether it really will be cracked in today's world or whether it's actually "can be cracked".